# How to give a child element the full height of its flex parent with Tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, css-position, tailwind-css

Currently I have a viewport with two `<div>` elements in it: the first on top for navigation, and the second, `#container`,  as a container for all my content. That `#container` is set to `flex-grow` so as to fill the remaining part of the viewport.

```
<template>
    <div class="min-h-screen  flex flex-col">
        <div class="flex-grow-0">
            <navBar :user="user" />
        </div>
        <div id="container" class="flex-grow  flex flex-col">
            <!-- Content is injected here, replacing router-view -->
            <router-view />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

In that injected content I have several `<div>` elements, of which I want the first one, `#landingPage`, to be the full height of the container.

```
<template>
    <div class="">
        <div id="landingPage" class="min-h-full">
            <!-- This div must be as tall as the container -->
            <p>First part</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <!-- This div and those that may follow don't matter -->
            <p>Second part</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

But when I set it to `min-h-full`, it doesn't grow at all and keeps the height of that `<p>`, and if I set it to `min-h-screen`, it of course overflows out of the viewport by an amount equal to the height of `<navBar>`.

I tried experimenting with more flex-classes, but this keeps the second `<div>` in view, when I just want `#landingPage` to be visible without scrolling.

How can I make this happen without giving the parent of `<navBar>` a `fixed` styling?

Answer (score -1):

If the component has multiple children and the last element has to fill the remaining height of the parent then we'd use `flex flex-col` on the parent and  `flex flex-grow` on the last children which has to fill the remaining height of the parent.

Something like:

```
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">
    <div>
        ....
    </div>
      
    <div class="flex flex-grow">
        This will take all the remaining height of the parent
    </div>
</div>
```